# How to run the invoice generator for multiple accounts?

Tags: php, curl

I have created script which generates pdf invoices, script is based on FPDF library. I have no problem to create an invoice for a single account, but how can I run it for multiple accounts. I passing the account numbers by curl, **http://localhost/xyz/xyz.php?account=1&account=2**, at the xyz.php I starting with $account = $_POST['account']; , where all other sql queries are executed for given account to gather the data. The script 'takes' only  last account number and saving invoice to file.

I able to pass 100 accounts to generator, but I dont know, how to run script 100 times for each account.

I tried with foreach but it doesnt work for me.

Comment: i suggest using command line access to the php script rather than curl:  `php /Path/To/xyz.php 1 2 3 ... 99 100`.  you'll need to change your script to accept command line arguments

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting your parameters. You should pass them as an array: `account[]=1&account[]=2` and then iterate over `$_GET['account']` to do what you want:

```
foreach ($_GET['account'] as $account_id) {
   // generate invoice...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `for` loop:

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 100; $i++){
    /* $i will increase from 1 to 100, so you can
    curl to http://localhost/xyz/xyz.php?account=$i */
}
```

---

Alternatively, send the GET variables with a separator, such as:

```
//localhost/xyz/xyz.php?account=1,3,5,10
```

and on the `xyz.php` page you can do a loop through them like:

```
//make $accounts an array of the account values
$accounts = explode(",", $_GET["account"]);

foreach($accounts as $account){
    //$account will be each value processed, e.g. 1, 3, 5, 10 etc
}
```